# Check if mail was sent succesfully in bash

Tags: bash, email

I have this bash script that sends to my email the new IP address if it has changed running on a crontab.

```
SUBJ="My new IP is "
EMAIL="myemail@gmail.com"

ip1=""
ip2=""

read ip1 < ip.txt
ip2=$(wget -qO- ifconfig.me/ip)

if [ "$ip1" = "$ip2" ]
then
  exit
else
  echo "$ip2" > ip.txt
  echo "$ip2" | mail -s "$SUBJ""$ip2" $EMAIL
  exit
fi
```

The problem is that if for any reason the email could not been sent, the `ip.text` file would still change, and the next time that the script runs `"$ip1" = "$ip2"` would be true and never send the email.

How can I check if the mail was sent successfully?

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=65010):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to ensure that the `mail` program ran successfully, use

```
echo "$ip2" | mail -s "$SUBJ $ip2" && echo "$ip2" > ip.txt
```

If you actually care about the mail being successfully *delivered* after `mail` sends it to your local mail transfer agent, there's not much you can do.